# XSL 1.0 difficulty splitting string

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have to use XSL 1.0 to solve the following problem.  I am a beginner to XSL, so please bear with me if it is trivial.

I use a file called transform.xsl to transform left.xml to right.xml.  I will show the files, then explain the logic.

Here is left.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<parties>
    <party>
        <id>123</id>
        <pending>456,789,234</pending>
        <name>NYC Film Festival</name>
    </party>

    <party>
        <id>345</id>
        <pending>234</pending>
        <name>Montreal Film Festival</name>
    </party>

    <party>
        <id>345</id>
        <pending />
        <name>LA Film Festival</name>
    </party>
</parties>
```

Here is right.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <parties>
        <Aparty name="NYC Film Festival" id="456"/>
        <Aparty name="NYC Film Festival" id="789"/>
        <Aparty name="NYC Film Festival" id="234"/>

        <Aparty name="Montreal Film Festival" id=234/>

        <Aparty name="LA Film festival" id=345>

    </parties>
```

The idea is as follows.  Consider the left.xml.  If the pending node inside party is empty, use id for right.xml.  Otherwise, split the content inside the pending tag and insert a node for each.  The splitting is throwing me off, especially since I have to use XSL 1.0

Can someone please help?

My current transform.xsl looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="parties">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="parties/party"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="parties/party">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="boolean(pending) and string(pending) != ''">
                <xsl:element name="Aparty">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="pending"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="Aparty">
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can process the list of pending values recursively in another template. The idea is to generate `Aparty` for the first pending id, then pass the remaining ids for next iteration to handle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="parties">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="parties/party"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="parties/party">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="boolean(pending) and string(pending) != ''">
        <xsl:call-template name="generateAparty">
          <xsl:with-param name="name" select="name"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="pending"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:element name="Aparty">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="generateAparty">
    <xsl:param name="name"/>
    <xsl:param name="ids"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($ids, ',') = false()">
        <!-- 1 id left -->
        <xsl:element name="Aparty">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$ids"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- Create element for 1st pending id in the list -->
        <xsl:element name="Aparty">
          <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($ids, ',')"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="generateAparty">
          <xsl:with-param name="name" select="$name"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="ids" select="substring-after($ids, ',')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```